# Is it a correct way to add layer to google maps?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, canvas

I want to add absolutely positioned canvas layer to google maps. This layer should not be affected by the map movements - it has to be just a static canvas that overlays map tiles and lies below the map controls. That's why I don't use different panes like floatPane, tilePane and so on.

Instead of this I add canvas directly to the mapControls. And it works - here's an example: http://jsfiddle.net/wcfPG/. But is this a correct way to add layer?

Here's the reason why I'm bothered with such fair detail: if we change #18 line in jsfiddle,

```
map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_CENTER].push(canvas);
```

to this one:

```
map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_LEFT].push(canvas);
```

or this one:

```
map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_LEFT].push(canvas);
```

there appears margin from left or right side. I don't know why, it seems that's protection for the google maps logo being always visible. I don't know why TOP_CENTER does not makes such margins and I'm afraid google can fix it every moment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Controls are designed to be non-overlapping.

The documentation says :

> Controls are positioned relative to other controls in the same layout
>   position. Controls that are added first are positioned closer to the
>   edge of the map.

You have discovered a way to add your own custom "control" but it is still subject to these positioning rules.

You may be better off trying to make a [Custom Overlay](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/overlays#CustomOverlays) rather than a custom control.

Comment: Thanks for you answer. There's one detail with custom overlays that I want to avoid. That is: if we add overlay to any map pane instead of map control, google appends it's DOM inside an absolutely-positioned container that is affected by map drag. There're seven types of map panes, and all are the same with the only difference in z-index. Every solution that works with map pane has to manually move overlay back to (0,0) position after each map move. I don't like this hack, that's why I want to place my overlay outside the draggable container, controls-level insertion gives exactly this.

Comment: Mmm, I see your point. You want hybrid behaviour. A non-dragging overlay, or a non-relative control. You could try your current approach with `.unshift(canvas)` replacing `.push(canvas)` but that will just mess around with the position of the standard control in the the same position.

Comment: Your best hopes appear to be (a) to place a custom control in an otherwise unoccupied position (as per your original TOP_CENTER), (b) penetrate and suppress the internal mechanism (CSS?) that causes controls to be positioned relative to other controls in the same position, or (c) penetrate and suppress the internal mechanism that causes a custom overlay to be draggable.

Comment: Try this - http://jsfiddle.net/pwp2R/1/ - more a demonstrator than a workable solution.

Comment: Yes, I understand Your example. That's natural that google does not observe positions of inserted div after generating it's DOM structure. And it seems I understand why TOP_CENTER works without timeout (as You noticed, it's empty otherwise in contrast to the TOP_LEFT and TOP_RIGHT containers). Thank You.

Comment: Yes and yes Kasheftin. I think we have the same understanding now.